# Toggle switch not working in chrome but in firefox is working

Tags: javascript

```
function toggle_it(itemID){

    // Toggle visibility between none and ''
    if ((document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'none')) {
          document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = ''
          event.preventDefault()

   } else {
          document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none';
          event.preventDefault()
   }
}
```

Comment: Please include a description of expected behaviour, what actually happens and any errors you see. A working example is always best (you can include runable snippets in your post, including HTML).

Comment: You should explain in detail what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: You are uisng `event.preventDefault()`,  but you are not passing `event`  as argument in your function.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle" onClick="toggle_it('trow1');toggle_it('trow2')"><img title="VIEW" src="img/view2.png" /></a>

Comment: And Its calling from <tr id="trow1" style="display:none;">
                                 <td colspan="8">
          <div class="row">
           <p><strong class="runtext" style="float:left;">Description&nbsp;:&nbsp;</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse ctetur adipisicing elit ..</p>
          </div>
    
         </td>
                                </tr>

Comment: Which version of chrome you are using. Its working fine here in chrome and firefox both.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get css `property` value is to use `getComputedStyle`

```
var div = document.getElementById(itemID);
if(window.getComputedStyle(div, null).getPropertyValue('display') == 'none'){

}
```

`getComputedStyle` is suported in every browser and in ie 9 or greater

Learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

And also when you change style `property` values
Instead of setting it empty change its value

INSTEAD

```
document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = ''
```

TO

```
document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none'
```

Comment: `getComputedStyle` is in general an anti-pattern. It's preferable to simply use classes, and add and remove them.